# Change uploaded image name in PHP

Tags: php

when i upload image with same name it replace my precending imagage. I want to give him number (increment that number) 1_name.png, 2_name.png. This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_im'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $location = 'uploads/';
    $target = 'uploads/'.$name;

    if(file_exists('uploads/'.$name)) {
        $i = 1;
        while(file_exists('uploads/'.$i."_".$name)) {
            $i++;
        }
        $name = $i."_".$name;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name)) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO obrazky(img,title) VALUES ('".$target."','$title')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    } else {
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Help with what? And why not just give image a random name?

Comment: And be aware of the SQL injection problem you have in that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it far simpler, just count the amount of files you have in your directory and increase it by 1.

```
$cntFiles = count(array_diff( scandir("/uploads"), array(".", "..") ));
$cntFiles++; // Increase by 1 for the next number
$name = $cntFiles."_".$name;
```

We do the `array_diff()` to remove the `.` and `..` entries that are coming from the file-system, but don't represent files in that directory.

Also, you have some issues in your code

```
$target = 'uploads/'.$name;

if(file_exists('uploads/'.$name)) {
    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists('uploads/'.$i."_".$name)) {/*...*/}
```

First, you're checking against 2 different filenames. The name is unlikely to be used at this point, because you're checking for the name that the file was uploaded with.

Second, you've defined a variable with the filename, but you're not using it.

```
$target = 'uploads/'.$name;
if(file_exists($target)) {/*...*/}
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), but that's covered in the linked question.

Comment: @Forlis If this answer has helped you, it would be good if you accept it with the green checkmark underneath the voting icons. This marks the question as answered.